# Symfony2 Doctrine2 fetch all table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-optimization

I need fetch all table and do some calculation in loop, what is bets way to do this, my example is :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$increment = 0;

for($i = 0; $i>= 0; $i++){
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('com')
        ->from('CatalogWebBundle:ComCompany', 'com')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setMaxResults(2000)
        ->setFirstResult($increment);

    $info = $query->getArrayResult();
    if(!$info)
        break;
    $increment += 2000;
}
```

What I get:

[image]

Query is not very slow 231ms, but PHP 6501s how to optimize this time to 1-2s it's possible ?

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `com_company` (
`cmp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cmp_category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_code` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_city` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_vat` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_emp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_return` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_return_from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_return_till` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_phone` bigint(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_site` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_ceo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_register` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cmp_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=95749 ;


ALTER TABLE `com_company`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cmp_id`), ADD KEY `cmp_city` (`cmp_city`), ADD KEY `cmp_category` (`cmp_category`);

ALTER TABLE `com_company`
MODIFY `cmp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=95749;

ALTER TABLE `com_company`
ADD CONSTRAINT `com_company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cmp_city`) REFERENCES `com_city` (`cit_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `com_company_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`cmp_category`) REFERENCES `com_category` (`cat_id`);
```

Maybe my server is too weak ? I need optimize this script to 1-2s max, it's possible ?

Server: [image]

Table - 100k record, table size - 23,6 MiB

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if the calculations must be done in PHP Code, or can be moved to SQL (MySQL procedures for instance). But if the latter is the case, I would advise you to take a look at MySQL Procedures. With your approach you are transferring a lot of data between the PHP Client and the MySQL Server. And the end this is not a very scalable solution.

Comment: I cant't do this inside mysql it's complec calculations, it's solution to do fast transfer between mysql -> php ?